# DatePicker not display the selected date

Tags: datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

i used datepicker in my web application. when i select a date, i have not the selected date(dd/mm/yy) but the result of view after selection date is : yy-1/mm-1/yyyy. 
Example : i would select 08/10/2015 but it's selected 07/09/2015 .

any help please  !

Comment: which version of bootstrap-datepicker do you use?

Comment: i use 1.11.2 as version

Comment: And you use eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker? Because the is no version 1.11.2

Comment: no  but I use datepicker of librairy jQUERY

Comment: Ok i will remove the bootstrap-datepicker tag as it's confusing

Comment: Ok. thank a lot for this correction